# display a C# winform in HTML

Tags: c#, html, winforms

After about 3 years of making small winform programs in C#, i'd like to post them to my website, is there any way i can just import the C# winform into HTML? searching the internet for help only shows me how to view websites in a C# winform, wich is not what i want.

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: Winform is meant to be a native GUI. You can't do it (maybe a converter exists. But i don't know any)

Comment: Take screenshots or put the .exe up for download. You can't trivially convert WinForms to WebForms.

Comment: What do you mean post them to your website?  Do you mean turn them into web applications? Or just create a download link?

Comment: @Trevor D, i mean turn them into web applications, or maybe a way to execute them straight from the browser without the user having to download and run it manually, but judging from the rest of the answers, this is impossible  without a rewrite to a webform. Unless you have some secrets you would like to share with us i guess i will look into webforms.